# How can i adjust text automatically in a QPushButton?

Tags: c++, qt, button, qpushbutton

I have the following button

```
ui->setMaximumWidth(121);
ui->setMinimumWidth(121);
ui->setMaximumHeight(80);
ui->setMinimumHeight(80);
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet   ("background-color: QLinearGradient(spread:pad x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0.0" + "#e5e4e2" + ",  stop: 0.4" + "#c0beb9" + ", stop: 1.0"+ "#e5e4e2"+");"
                                            "color: #868479; "
                                            "border-style: solid;"
                                            "border-style: solid;"
                                            "border-radius: 7;"
                                            "padding: 3px;"
                                            "padding-left: 5px;"
                                            "padding-right: 5px;"
                                            "border-color: #339;"
                                            "border-width: 1px;"
                                            "font:Bold;"
                                            "font-family:Georgia");

ui->pushButton->setText("Administración de Empresas");
```

But "Administración de Empresas" is a too long word then i cannot see the complete phrase.

Ps: i dont want to do it manually, i want that my app detect large phrases and adjust it automatically

Comment: What do you want to get, what do you mean by adjusting? Does it mean enlarging the button or reducing the font size?

Comment: @eyllanesc i mean the font size

Answer (score 1):

It should be automatically fit to the text of push button.

make sure you using QLayout in correct way.

If you are manually setting the size in code, you can use the sizeHint property to get the right dimensions:

```
button->resize(button->sizeHint().width(), button->sizeHint().height());
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: But i dont want to resize my QPushButton. If i have to resize something it should be my text. But it would be better if it can put a new line (\n )

Comment: @Eduardo123  Resize text ? you mean decrease font size ?  it's bad for your design.  you should use QLayout and do it automatically.

Comment: How can i desing a QPushButton using QLayout?

Comment: @Eduardo123 In designer you can use `QHLayout` or `QVLayout` and use widgets to group items.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it not good practic. But if you need to do word wrap on QPushButton, you can do it through QLayout:

```
QHBoxLayout *pLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
QLabel *pTextLabel = new QLabel();

pTextLabel->setText("This is a very very very long text");
pTextLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
pTextLabel->setWordWrap(true);
pTextLabel->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
pTextLabel->setMouseTracking(false);
pTextLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

pLayout->addWidget(pTextLabel);

MyButton->setText("");
MyButton->setLayout(pLayout);
```

But you have got a problem with automatic resize QButton height